# Debug liquid for Shopify

Tags: shopify

I'm really puzzled and can't understand why my `{{ time }}` returns an empty value.

I'm trying to calculate the difference between the time currently and a booking time in Shopify. For the booking I have the date (first line_item.property) and the time (second one) coming separately. I want to add one to another and then compare it to the current time, but before I can do the math I have tried to display the different variables I have created.
`{{ now }}` & `{{ date }}` work fine but for `{{ time }}` it returns an empty value. On the other hand if instead of assigning it a value name I just display the `line.item.property` it works just fine.

Can you help me understand what I am doing wrong here?

```
  {% assign today = 'now' | date: '%s' %}
  {% for order in customer.orders %}
    {%- for line_item in order.line_items -%}
      {% for property in line_item.properties limit:1 %} 
        {% assign date = property.last | date: '%s' %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% for property in line_item.properties offset:1 %}
        {% assign time = property.last | date: '%s' %}
      {% endfor %}
    {%- endfor -%}
    {{ now }} - {{ date }} - {{ time }}
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: So I have been able to move forward by using capture instead of assign but I'm stuck just a step further.

I have now been able to extract the current time and date as well as the booking time and date. I have also captured the difference between the current date and the booking date and the current time and the booking time.

But when I want to check if the difference is positive or negative I get an error saying "Liquid error: comparison of String with 0 failed".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `plus: 0` you can convert the `string` to `integer`, this will enable math operation for your comparison.

```
  {% assign today = 'now' | date: '%s' | plus: 0 %}
```

check with `{% unless line_item.properties ==  empty %}` to see if properties exist.

`{% assign date = property.last | date: '%s' %}` , the variable `property.last` must follow a well-formatted dates for `date` to work. [liquid-date-format](https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/liquid-date-format)

```
{% for property in line_item.properties offset:1 %}
        {% assign time = property.last | date: '%s' %}
      {% endfor %}
```

problem with `offset:1`, if the array only has 1 `line_item.properties` this will not run at all.  Hence `time` is empty; or it exist but `property.last` does not have a `date` format.

```
{% assign today = 'now' | date: '%s' | plus: 0 %}
{% for order in customer.orders %}
  {%- for line_item in order.line_items -%}

    {% unless line_item.properties == empty %}
        {% for property in line_item.properties %}
            {% if forloop.index == 1 %}
                {% assign date = property.last | date: '%s' | plus: 0 %}
                {% if date == 0 %}
                    {% comment %}Opp! Not A Date, Terminate loop{% endcomment %}
                    {% break %}
                {% endif %}
            {% else %}
                {% assign time = property.last | date: '%s' | plus: 0 %}
                {% unless time == 0 %}
                    {% assign date = date - time %}
                {% endunless %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endunless %}
{% endfor %}

{{today - date}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Charles that really unblocked me.
Posting here the final version I went with as I needed to compare exact time and not simply the date of the order.

```
      {% assign now_date = 'now' | date: '%s' | plus: 0 %}
  {% assign now_time = 'now' | date: '%s' | plus: 0 %}
    {% for order in customer.orders %}
        {%- for line_item in order.line_items -%}
            {% for property in line_item.properties limit:1 %}
                {% assign booking_date = property.last | date: '%s' | plus: 0 %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% for property in line_item.properties offset:1 limit:1 %}
                {% assign booking_time = property.last | date: '%s' | plus: 0 %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% assign date_to_compare = booking_date | plus: '86400' %}
                {% unless now_date > date_to_compare %}
                  {% if now_time <= booking_time or now_date <= booking_date %}SEANCE A VENIR{% endif %}            
                {% endunless %}
        {%- endfor -%}
    {% endfor %}
```